# T-SQL : Pivot table without aggregate

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I am trying to understand how to pivot data within T-SQL but can't seem to get it working. I have the following table structure

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+
|       Name        |         Value         |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
| TaskId            | 12417                 |
| TaskUid           | XX00044497            |
| TaskDefId         | 23                    |
| TaskStatusId      | 4                     |
| Notes             |                       |
| TaskActivityIndex | 0                     |
| ModifiedBy        | Orange                |
| Modified          | /Date(1554540200000)/ |
| CreatedBy         | Apple                 |
| Created           | /Date(2121212100000)/ |
| TaskPriorityId    | 40                    |
| OId               | 2                     |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

I want to pivot the name column to be columns expected output

```
+--------+------------------------+-----------+--------------+-------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+-----+
| TASKID |        TASKUID         | TASKDEFID | TASKSTATUSID | NOTES | TASKACTIVITYINDEX | MODIFIEDBY |       MODIFIED        | CREATEDBY |        CREATED        | TASKPRIORITYID | OID |
+--------+------------------------+-----------+--------------+-------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+-----+
|        |                        |           |              |       |                   |            |                       |           |                       |                |     |
| 12417  | XX00044497             | 23        | 4            |       | 0                 | Orange     | /Date(1554540200000)/ | Apple     | /Date(2121212100000)/ | 40             | 2   |
+--------+------------------------+-----------+--------------+-------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+-----+
```

Is there an easy way of doing it? The columns are fixed (not dynamic).

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from yourtable
pivot
(
 min(value)
 for Name in ([TaskID],[TaskUID],[TaskDefID]......)
) as pivotable
```

You can also use **case statements**.
You must use the aggregate function in the pivot table.

If you want to learn more, here is the reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Output (I only tried three columns):

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=deefcc98853137d61e1f12f8eefc762d)